# Executing py2exe fails with can't open file 'setup.py'

Tags: python, py2exe

I'm using py2exe and I get the following errors in command prompt.

```
   C:\Users\Me>C:\Python26\My_scripts\python.exe setup.py py2exe
   C:\Python26\My_scripts\python.exe: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such
   file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `setup.py` located? Python is going to look in the directory you invoke it from, not in the directory where it (`python.exe`) is located.

Comment: It's in the same directory as python.exe. How do I tell which directory I Invoked it from, or specify where it should look for setup.py?

Comment: That's what I was guessing. I'll follow up with an answer since it would be a bit much to put here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your comment confirmed what I expected, I'll follow up with an answer post.

You invoked python from the directory you were in when you called the executable. In this case, according to your prompt, you invoked it from `C:\Users\Me`. Therefore, python is trying to find `setup.py` under this directory (which doesn't exist). You can either:

1) Change directories to the location of the `setup.py` file, then invoke python. The full path to the python executable will be necessary if it's not in your PATH or if it's in a different directory, otherwise it is not:

```
C:\Users\Me> cd C:\Python26\My_Scripts
C:\Python26\My_Scripts> C:\Python26\My_Scripts\python.exe  setup.py py2exe
```

2) Point python to the absolute path of `setup.py`:

```
C:\Users\Me> C:\Python26\My_Scripts\python.exe "C:\Python26\My_Scripts\setup.py" py2exe
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no file called `setup.py` in the `C:\Users\Me` directory.  Various possible mistakes you could be making, of which the two likeliest ones:

1. the file might be in the directory in question but with a wrong name (say `settup.py`, oops, two Ts where one was needed) -- then, rename the file!
2. the file might be in another directory -- then, `cd` to that directory and try again!

Of course, *both* errors might be happening at the same time (in which case you need to fix both).

If you think you made neither mistake show us a `dir *.py` (from the `Me`) directory...